# Addition of an .onReceive closure to SwiftUI List -> Weird errors

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

I've been beating my head against this for a few hours and I'm starting to go crazy. I have a SwiftUI view, defined like this:

```
struct ExistingClaims: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel = ExistingClaimsListModel()
  @EnvironmentObject var newClaim : NewClaimModel

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
      List(viewModel.claims) { dataItem in
        NavigationLink(destination: ClaimDetails()){
          HStack(spacing: 10){
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
              Text(dataItem.subject)
              Text(String(dataItem.caseNumber)).font(.subheadline).italic()
            }
          }
        }
      }
      // Navigation Bar
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Exisitng Claims"), displayMode: .inline)
      // Navigation bar button
      .navigationBarItems(
        leading: Button("Logout") {
          self.viewModel.claims = []
          UserAccountManager.shared.logout()
        },
        trailing: NavigationLink(
        destination: NewClaim()) {
          Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
      )
    }
    .onAppear{
      print("On Appear firing for ExistingClaims()")
      self.viewModel.fetchDataFromSalesforce()
    }
  }
}
```

All this works fine. Until i try to add an .onReceive clause to the List like this:

```
List(viewModel.claims) { dataItem in
    NavigationLink(destination: ClaimDetails()){
      HStack(spacing: 10){
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3) {
          Text(dataItem.subject)
          Text(String(dataItem.caseNumber)).font(.subheadline).italic()
        }
      }
    }
  }.onReceive(self.newClaim.complete){ data in
    print(data)
  }
```

As soon as I add that onReceive I get a really odd error - shown in this screen shot:
[image: Screenshot showing error]

Any ideas what's going on? My end goal is to refresh the list data when the environmentobject's published property (or state, I've tried both) update

Comment: My guess is there is something wrong in your onReceive call and not with the line indicated by the compiler. Unhelpful error messages are still quite common with SwiftUI or function builders in general. For example, is NewClaimModel.complete really a publisher and accessible by the given view? Is it maybe a @Published property and you are missing the lifting operator, i.e., did you mean self.newClaim.$complete?

Comment: Edit your question to include the declaration of the `complete` property of `NewClaimModel`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `NewClaimModel`, but assume it should be as follows

```
  }.onReceive(self.newClaim.$complete){ data in // .$complete is Publisher
    print(data)
  }
```